# Point a subdomain directly to a file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a jar file that I would like to make easily accessible to users with a simple subdomain. Currently, they visit `https://subdomain.example.com/application.jar` and that directly starts the download of the application. I would prefer to shorten it to just `https://subdomain.example.com/` and when they browse to that link, the link is either redirected (maybe `.htaccess`) to the `application.jar` resource, or perhaps there is some code on an index page that kick-starts the download of the application.

This subdomain is specifically for the application. It's essentially `https://application.example.com/application.jar`. There are no other pages or content being served. Just a simple link for a direct resource download. What is the best and simplest method to achieve this?

I have tried pointing the DNS record directly to the resource. That was a no go. I have tried a 301 redirect, but I may have done it incorrectly. I have not yet tried an index page with maybe some JavaScript because this feels like an overly complex and prone to failure method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set [`DirectoryIndex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex):

```
DirectoryIndex application.jar
```

The following lines need [`mod_headers`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) and will provide a proper filename for the download:

```
<Files application.jar>
    ForceType application/java-archive
    Header set Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=application.jar"
</Files>
```

However, as I already suspected not all clients respect these headers. With Chrome I got the correct filename in my testes, wget ignores it and stores the file as `index.html`

Overall a 301 would be more appropriate. A working redirect would be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule   ^ - [L]
RewriteRule   ^ "/application.jar"  [R]
```

This will redirect any path on that subdomain that doesn't exist as a file to `/application.jar`.

Comment: DirectoryIndex works, and honestly that is probably my preferred solution, however, its behaving a bit strangely. The download now works using the shortened link, but its giving the jar file its own custom random name? Is this expected behavior? Why doesn't it download as application.jar?

Comment: Yes, that's expected behaviour. No filename is provided, so the client has to make one up. A 301 redirect would resolve this properly. Alternatively you can inject a header that provides the filename. However, I wouldn't expect every client to interpret that correctly.

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer with a 301 redirect example? I don't have the test I did anymore. I deleted it after a few failed attempts. Thank you for help! Will mark answered shortly.

Comment: @Atomiklan I expanded the original example along with it's caveats and added a redirect example.

Comment: Flawless solution! Thank you very much for the help!